# create multidimensional object from array assigning a value from this array as key in the new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this (each contain more than 2 key-values pairs,I just use 2 for the question)

```
[{"name":"Joe", "id":17}, {"name":"Bob", "id":17}, {"name":"Carl", "id": 35},{"name":"son", "id": 31},{"name":"smith", "id": 29},{"name":"tom", "id": 35}]
```

I would like to set a multidimensional object like this.
for every DISTINC "id" and inside this "id" contain "id", "name" values .

```
{
'17' : {
    {"name":"Joe",
    "id":17},
    {"name":"Bob",
    "id":17}
},
'35' : {
    {"name":"Carl", "id": 35},
    {"name":"tom", "id": 35}
},
'31':{"name":"son", "id": 31}
},
 '29':{"name":"smith", "id": 29}
}
```

As you see I want to assign distinct "id" as key on first object

I think I may misuse brackets, sorry for that, please correct me on this too.

Comment: What's your question? How to create the muldimensional object or what's the best way to structured your data?

Comment: create the multidimensional as I said in the title . thanks

Comment: Why are you storing the id multiple times? Three times for 17 and 35. Seems redundant

Comment: right @Tdelang. as I said there many other values in the array anyway, consider if were any other . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over your data and add it to a new object or append it, depending if it already exists.

```js
var data = [{"name":"Joe", "id":17}, {"name":"Bob", "id":17}, {"name":"Carl", "id": 35},{"name":"son", "id": 31},{"name":"smith", "id": 29},{"name":"tom", "id": 35}];

var new_data = {};

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    if (new_data.hasOwnProperty(data[i].id))
        new_data[data[i].id].push(data[i]);
    else
        new_data[data[i].id] = [data[i]];
}
document.getElementById("new_data").textContent = JSON.stringify(new_data, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="new_data"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd be lazy and use [`underscore`](http://underscorejs.org/). It has a function called [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) which does exactly what you need:

```
_.groupBy(arr, 'id');
```

[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3vk9v8mz/)

Comment: this is not lazy since I have to read about underscore but @gre_gor answer is for the concept of the question , even thought I may probably use this

Answer (score 0):

Why not just populate a new object?

```
var obj = {};

var arr = [{"name":"Joe", "id":17}, {"name":"Bob", "id":17}, {"name":"Carl", "id": 35},{"name":"son", "id": 31},{"name":"smith", "id": 29},{"name":"tom", "id": 35}];

arr.forEach(function(k) {
   obj[k.id] = k;
})
```